# admin right to IIS7 for user using group policy or script?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, scripting, iis-7.5, vbscript

I want to provide administrator rights to user account under windows 7 just for IIS7 and user shouldn't be able to manage any other application. I have create group policy rules using applocker for windows7 where user can manage all the installed application, but it doesn't works for IIS7 as it need admin rights.

Can we do this using group policy or by adding scripts under group policy for users. Also any vbscript which can provide admin rights to IIS7 for a particular user will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In II7 you can delegate management access using the "Management Service" feature at the server level.  You can use a windows or an IIS user to grant permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply Scott, just for others who are interested in setting Management service under IIS7, can refer to below URL.

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/159/configuring-remote-administration-and-feature-delegation-in-iis-7/